# Does a converge series has a sum that growing not slower than a linear function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider a series $a_n \in {\mathbb R}_+$ ($n \in {\mathbb Z}_+$) with
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0.
\end{equation}

It is easy to find an example that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = \infty.
\end{equation}
For example $a_n = 1/n$ or $a_n = 1/\log(n)$.

However, does such a $a_n$ exist that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = 0$ and

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = c,
\end{equation}
where $c > 0$?

PS: For $a_n = 1/n$ or $a_n = 1/\log(n)$, it can be verified that $c=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence $(a_n)$ is convergence and $a_n\to L$, it can be shown that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = L
$$
also. So basically, you **cannot** find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that $lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$ while
$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i > 0$

For more information, see [Cesàro summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) from wikipedia.

Comment: I've edited my answer to (hopefully) match your question :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is true with each $a_1 = 1$.
We note:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n 1 =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} n = 1$$

Comment: Thanks, but $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$ seems not $0$

Comment: sorry, my question initially confusing, and I have re-edited it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you were looking for that condition. Bigbear's answer implies that no such sequence exists.